# Let F be a field. Prove that if $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $f(a)=0$ for some $a \in F$, then $f(x)$ is reducible if deg(f) > 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be a field. Prove that if $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $f(a)=0$ for some $a \in F$, then $f(x)$ is reducible if deg(f) > 1.

Can someone provide me with some hint how I can proceed with this question? Thank you.

Comment: You should know that $f(a) = 0$ iff $x - a \mid f(x)$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Just to make sure i understand: since x−a | f(x), f(x) = (x-a)g(x), deg f(x) = deg(x-a) + deg(g(x)) = 1 + deg(g(x)). Since degree f(x) > 1, deg g(x) >= 1. Hence g(x) is not a unit, therefore since both g(x) and x-a are not unit, f(x) is reducible

Comment: @123, great, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F$ is a field, the Euclidean algorithm holds in $F[x]$.  This implies we may write

$f(x) = (x - a)q(x) + r(x) \tag{1}$

for some *unique* $q(x), r(x) \in F[x]$, with either $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r < \deg (x - a) = 1$.  If $r(x) = 0$, then from (1)

$f(x) = (x - a)q(x); \tag{2}$

if perchance $r(x) \ne 0$, then $\deg r = 0$ and so $r \in F$ and then evaluating (1) at $x = a$ yields

$0 = f(0) = (a - a)q(a) +r = r, \tag{2}$

contradicting the assumption $r(x) \ne 0$; we see that (2) must bind.  Since $\deg(x - a) = 1$ and

$1 < \deg f = \deg (x - a) + \deg q, \tag{3}$

we have

$\deg q > 0; \tag{4}$

thus $f(x)$, being the product of the two polynomials $x - a, q(x) \in F[x]$ of positive degree, is reducible in $F[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(a)=0 \Leftrightarrow x-a | f(x)$ Since deg f>1 then $f(x) \not = x-a$ (as polynomials) hence $x-a$ is a proper non trivial factor of $f(x)$ and hence $f(x)$ is reducible.

Comment: Not $\,f \neq x\!-\!a\,$ but, rather, $\,f\nmid x\!-\!a\,$ or, equivalently, $\,x\!-\!a\,$ is a *proper* factor of $f\ \ $